# Error When Upgrading To 5.17

Tags: wordpress, civicrm-home

Wordpress install. Deleted out the CiviCRM folder like many times before. Reinstalled the new one. Get the following error:  Error Details

> An error of type E_COMPILE_ERROR was caused in line 834 of the file
>   /home/xxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php. Error
>   message: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear')

Answer (score 1):

It's complaining about not being able to open `CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php`  Does that file exist?  Are the permissions correct to allow the webserver to read that file?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that you forgot to copy your civicrm.settings.php file into the new plugins/civicrm folder.  See the docs at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/

Comment: I don't think that path is right. That's the old one pre CiviCRM 4.7. civicrm.settings.php should be in uploads/civicrm so should not need to be copied or put back during the upgrade process.